# Getting Firefox´s History (places.sqlite) with PowerShell

Tags: sqlite, powershell, firefox

i need powershell script (or help) for exporting data from places.sqlite in Mozilla Firefox. Also DATE from moz_historyvisits (from unixepoch to localtime), URL and TITLE (only with text, no blank) from moz_places to txt file with ;$ separator (date;$url;$title). 
Export - for every launching of Firefox adds only new rows or missing or deleted links in txt file ((date;$url;$title). Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried? Have any work to show? What part exactly are you stuck at? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you need help learning how to code or troubleshoot something then this is the place for you. If you need code from scratch then you should hire a developer.

Comment: I have tried only sqlite3 for exporting data from places.sqlite to txt file:             sqlite3 places.sqlite "select datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as datum, moz_places.url, moz_places.title from moz_places, moz_historyvisits where moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id and moz_places.title like '%' order by datum" >> test.txt

Comment: I see you are new to Stackoverflow. Please provide code so we can test why whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to pipe csv from sqlite to powershell.  You can also google loading an sqlite library in powershell.  http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/SQLite-and-PowerShell/

```
sqlite3 -csv -header places.sqlite "select datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as datum, moz_places.url, moz_places.title from moz_places, moz_historyvisits where moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id and moz_places.title like '%' order by datum" |
  convertfrom-csv | select -last 3 | fl

datum : 2017-07-16 09:55:36
url   : http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default
title : Get Silverlight | Microsoft Silverlight

datum : 2017-07-16 09:55:57
url   : https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/3/E/03EB1393-4F4E-4191-8364-C641FAB20344/50901.00/Silverlight.dmg
title : Silverlight(1).dmg

datum : 2017-07-16 09:58:14
url   : https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Scott-Hanselman-amp-Jeffrey-Snover-Discuss-Windows-PowerShell
title : Scott Hanselman & Jeffrey Snover Discuss Windows PowerShell | Charles | Channel 9
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I need 1 row for date, url, title with ";$" separator, for example: 2019-05-13 09:06:38;$http://www.microsoft.com;$Get Silverlight, second row: 2019-05=13 09:07:13;$http://www.channel9.msdn.com;$Channel9 and for every launching of Firefox adds only new rows or missing or deleted links in txt file. How do I compare old places.sqlite and new places.sqlite?

Comment: Now my code is: .\sqlite3 -csv -header places.sqlite "select datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as date, moz_places.url, moz_places.title from moz_places, moz_historyvisits where moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id and moz_places.title like '%' order by date" |
  convertfrom-csv | fl > test.txt and code page I need "UTF8 no BOM" but I have it in "ANSI".

Comment: @"frank smooth" If it's all ascii characters, there's no difference between ansi and utfi 8 no bom.  Why do you need powershell at all?  You can save the csv from squlite3 directly to a file.

Comment: I upload the data then to other database and I need txt file code in UTF8 without BOM for correct upload.